# Thread safety for deterministic one-time write to static location?

Tags: c++, multithreading, static, cpuid

I'm checking CPUID flags on x86-64 for instruction set extensions, and caching the results in a static array. The function doing this may be called from any of several different threads, so race conditions are possible - but does this matter? Any thread will produce the same results, so I don't care about conflicting writes, and checking the same flags more than once is a non-issue. My conclusion is that this is safe, but am I missing something?

Here's a stripped-down version of what I'm doing:

```cpp
enum class Arch : int
{
    SSE2,
    AVX,
    MAX
};

static bool CheckCPUID(Arch arch)
{
    // Check CPU features
}

static bool IsSupportedArch(Arch arch)
{
    enum class TriVal : int
    {
        Unknown,
        True,
        False
    };

    constexpr int arch_max = static_cast<int>(Arch::MAX);
    const int i_arch = static_cast<int>(arch);

    // Cache results in-memory:
    static TriVal cached_results[arch_max - 1] = { TriVal::Unknown, TriVal::Unknown };

    if (cached_results[i_arch] == TriVal::Unknown)
    {
        cached_results[i_arch] = CheckCPUID(arch) ? TriVal::True : TriVal::False;
    }

    return cached_results[i_arch] == TriVal::True;
}
```

Comment: having multiple threads write to the same location without synchronization causes a data race which is undefined behavior.  When do these threads that need this information get created?'

Comment: You can do this using a so called Meyer's singleton https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/thread-safe-initialization-of-a-singleton this pattern is threadsafe from C++11 onward, assuming you initialize only once and then only read from it from the other threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so I don't care about conflicting writes

Conflicting writes to non-atomic objects are a *data race* and a data race *always* causes undefined behavior. The compiler may optimize based on that.

Therefore you must care about this.

You can use a `std::array<TriVal, arch_max - 1>` for the `static` local variable `cached_results` and have it be set in its initializer. The initialization of static local variables is guaranteed to be thread-safe and executed exactly once (assuming C++11 or later).

```
static bool IsSupportedArch(Arch arch)
{
    enum class TriVal : int
    {
        Unknown,
        True,
        False
    };

    constexpr int arch_max = static_cast<int>(Arch::MAX);
    const int i_arch = static_cast<int>(arch);

    // Cache results in-memory:
    static const auto cached_results = []{
        std::array<TriVal, arch_max-1> cached_results;
        
        // loop here to set the whole array

        return cached_results;
    }();

    return cached_results[i_arch] == TriVal::True;
}
```

Alternatively you can mark the variable `thread_local`, but in that case every thread will call CPUID once.

If you really care that CPUID is called only as few number of times as required, you can make the array elements `std::atomic`s:

```
static std::atomic<TriVal> cached_results[arch_max - 1]{};
```

In that case it is ok to have concurrent writes and as you say you don't care about which one ends up being the value. You probably want to replace the loads and stores with relaxed memory order operations though, since you don't need the default `seq_cst` guarantees:

```
static bool IsSupportedArch(Arch arch)
{
    enum class TriVal : int
    {
        Unknown,
        True,
        False
    };

    constexpr int arch_max = static_cast<int>(Arch::MAX);
    const int i_arch = static_cast<int>(arch);

    // Cache results in-memory:
    static std::atomic<TriVal> cached_results[arch_max - 1]{};

    auto value = cached_results[i_arch].load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

    if (value == TriVal::Unknown)
    {
        // OK only if CheckCPUID is guaranteed to always
        // return the same value
        value = CheckCPUID(arch) ? TriVal::True : TriVal::False;
        cached_results[i_arch].store(value, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

    return value == TriVal::True;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I asked! I'll probably go with the static initializer and let the compiler worry about this.

Comment: @Wacov The disadvantage of that approach is that the first thread calling `IsSupportedArch` will check all CPUID flags, which may delay it for longer than you can accept. Beware of that. Also as a side note: Why is the function marked `static`? If the function is `static`, then each translation unit will have its own copy of it with its own `cached_results` which will be initialized once in each translation unit.

Comment: @Wacov Also I forgot to add that this is only thread-safe since C++11, which I assume you are using (otherwise `std::array` and `enum class` won't work either). But if you are using C++98 or C++03, then you'll have bigger issues anyway since these versions of the standard were not thread-aware at all.

Comment: Not worried about the delay, it's only a handful of flags - should've done it that way from the start, really! It was `static` as it's in an inline code file, but that's a good point and another thing I should change.
And yes, C++11, thank god.